# Prove $(x+yz)(y'+x)(y'+z')=x(y'+z')$ in Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

How can we prove $(x+yz)(y'+x)(y'+z')=x(y'+z')$ in a Boolean algebra $B$?

Answer (score 4):

The first two factors simplified to $$(x+yz)(y'+x)$$

$$=(x+yz)(x+y')$$ $$=x+\{(yz).y'\}$$ $$=x+0$$ $$=x$$

Comment: How did you get from the second step to the third step?

Answer (score 4):

One way is proof by exhaustion:

\begin{matrix}
x & y & z & (x+yz)(y'+x)(y'+z') & x(y'+z')\\
\hline
False & False & False & False & False \\
False & False & True & False & False \\
False & True & False & False & False \\
False & True & True & False & False \\
True & False & False & True & True \\
True & False & True & True & True \\
True & True & False & True & True \\
True & True & True & False & False
\end{matrix}
Since the values match for any assignment of $(x,y,z)$, they are equal.

Comment: Great illustration!  +